# Converting to Encoding Cyclical Features in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I try to convert the month, weak and dayofyear columns into Cyclical Features  (sin, cos) , my **python code** is like this :

```
def encode(data, col, max_val):
data[col + '_sin'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * data[col]/max_val)
data[col + '_cos'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * data[col]/max_val)
return data
```

The code in **pyspark** is this :

```
df = df.withColumn('month_sin',np.sin(2 * np.pi * df['month']/12))
```

I get this **error**:

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Column which has no callable sin method
```

The column type of month is integer , I converted it to float and double but it did not help .

**Note**: The column has no zero (0) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use PySpark [`sin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sin) and python `math.pi` instead of `np`